# could ConcurrentLinkedDeque clear be implemented as resetting head tail pointer?

Tags: java

```
/**
 * Removes all of the elements from this deque.
 */
public void clear() {
    while (pollFirst() != null)
        ;
}
```

current implementation is just pop the elements in the queue one by one, but could that be done by just resetting the head and tail pointer term to an empty queue ?
what's need to be taken care here?

Comment: In general you do not want unused object references in the queue keep unused objects from being garbage collected. Probably pollFirst does some nulling. Also resetting head and tail - though really attractive - must be guarded too.

Answer (score 0):

The `pollFirst()` method does a lot more than just pop items from the queue. It does it in a thread-safe manner.

```
public E pollFirst() {
    for (Node<E> p = first(); p != null; p = succ(p)) {
        E item = p.item;
        if (item != null && p.casItem(item, null)) {
            unlink(p);
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Since you want to keep your concurrent collection concurrent, one way is to make sure you're using already concurrent operations, such as `pollFirst()`.

It's also worth noting that `clear()` is "less important" as an operation compared to others, so even though it might be possible to implement it differently, doing so would be of little use.

Comment: okay, considering that purely for theoretical purposes, is it possible to just reseting the pointers and get things right?

Comment: I doubt that very much. They're very advanced data structures for a reason.